# Using WSO2 FHIR Connector

Tags: rest, wso2, connector, hl7-fhir, wso2-esb

I'm trying the FHIR Connector with WSO2 EI 6.1.0
I'm following this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+FHIR+resources)

The request for the **create** operation is:

```
{
  "body": {
       "base": "https://sqlonfhir-stu3.azurewebsites.net",
      "type": "Patient",
      "format": "json"
      }
}
```

My proxy is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="fhirTest"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property expression="json-eval($.body.base)"
                   name="base"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.body.type)"
                   name="type"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.body.format)"
                   name="format"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>

         <fhir.init>
            <base>{$ctx:base}</base>
         </fhir.init>
         <fhir.create>
            <type>{$ctx:type}</type>
            <format>{$ctx:format}</format>
         </fhir.create>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="ApplicationXMLBuilder.allowDTD">true</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

After the request the response is (the body is void):

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 05 May 2017 14:09:01 GMT
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
```

but I get the following exception: DOCTYPE is not allowed

log:

```
[2017-05-05 16:09:01,192] []  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/fhirTest,From: 192.168.81.118,Direction: request,base1 = https://sqlonfhir-stu3.azurewebsites.net
,type1 = Patient,format1 = json,Payload: {
  "body": {
       "base": "https://sqlonfhir-stu3.azurewebsites.net",
          "type": "Patient",
          "format": "json"
      }
}
[2017-05-05 16:09:01,704] [] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:160)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.buildMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:817)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:546)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:118)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:281)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:775)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:36)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 21 more
[2017-05-05 16:09:01,709] [] ERROR - Axis2SynapseEnvironment Error while building message
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:283)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:142)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.buildMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:817)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:546)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:118)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:281)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:775)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at ...
[2017-05-05 16:11:03,952] []  WARN - SynapseCallbackReceiver Synapse received a response for the request with message Id : urn:uuid:c14afbec-7e12-4c9a-be5e-0746
53fed0e6 But a callback is not registered (anymore) to process this response
```

My questions are:

1. Has anyone been able to take the correct tests by following the guide?
2. How do I pass the other data to create the resource fhir (further base, type and format) as described [here](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/http.html#create)?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**: After I have enabled messageBuilder and messageFormatter (as suggested by Hariprasath) the previus error is resolved 
but now I have an other error:

```
[2017-05-10 16:42:20,891] [] DEBUG - RelayUtils Content Type is application/fhir+json; charset=utf-8
[2017-05-10 16:42:20,893] [] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:211
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the response is an HTML page(with the content-type is in text/html format). Usually, we need to enable the following formatter and builder to avoid this error and supports text/html format. Please add following message builders and formatters to the sections in /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml.

```
<messageBuilder contentType="text/html"
    class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>

<messageFormatter contentType="text/html"
    class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this resolve the "DOCTYPE is not allowed" error. I have update the question since I have other error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you add/enable builders and formatter for "text/html" in  /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file.

```
<messageFormatter contentType="text/html"
        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-fhir/blob/master/src/test/INTEGRATION-TEST.txt